# How to handle speaker change with Android Oboe library?

Tags: android, audio, oboe

I'm trying to implement Oboe library to my project to perform the least latency when playing sounds. I could perform playback manipulating, panning, mixing, the basics things which internal Android library such as `SoundPool` can provide.

I wanted to test panning effect, I connected headphones to my device, but then, I noticed that any sound didn't play through my headphones. Device speaker also didn't play any sound either. So I disconnected my headphones to check if something went wrong. I pressed sound playing button, but I couldn't hear any sound even though headphones are completely disconnected from device.

When I firstly open the app, it can play sound through device speaker without any problems, but as soon as I connect headphones, no sound plays through both device speaker and headphones.

Same for opposite, if I start app with headphones connected to device, it can play sound very well through headphones. It can even perform panning effect too, but if I disconnect headphones from device, it stops playing any sound.

1. Do I have to re-open audio stream whenever preferred audio device is changed?
2. If yes for 1, is there any way to notify app that audio device is changed, so I can manually close stream and re-open it? Or can I make Oboe automatically handle audio device changes?

Comment: Comment here if you need some sample C++ code I made, I will edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open a new audio stream when primary audio device changes as stated here in [oboe full guide.](https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/docs/FullGuide.md#disconnected-audio-stream) Oboe will handle the detection of device change for you automatically if you configure it.

> Disconnected audio stream An audio stream can become disconnected at
> any time if one of these events happens:
>
> The associated audio device is no longer connected (for example when
> headphones are unplugged). An error occurs internally. An audio device
> is no longer the primary audio device. - When a stream is disconnected,
> it has the state "Disconnected" and calls to write() or other
> functions will return Result::ErrorDisconnected. When a stream is
> disconnected, all you can do is close it.

Here is an example

```
void OboeStreamCallback::onErrorAfterClose(AudioStream *stream, Result result) {
    if (result == oboe::Result::ErrorDisconnected) {
        LOGI("Restarting AudioStream after disconnect");
        soundEngine.restart(); // please check oboe samples for soundEngine.restart(); call
    }
}
```

Also there is a special case for Android P. [Please read this, its important!](https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/docs/notes/disconnect.md)

Comment: Yes! I didn't know there was full guide. I really need to read that carefully now. Thanks a lot